# Converting dBuA to dBuV at 3m and 10m

Tags: rf, emc

I'm looking for some advice on converting from dBuA/m to dBuV/m at 10m. I'm trying to convert 10dBuA/m @ 10m.

I'm struggling with the uA to uV conversion at distance and can't find online tools to do this, and I'm struggling to find any equations I can work through.

I'm assuming I need to work through some other steps (maybe field strength) to get my result. Unfortunately RF calculations isn't my background or experience.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with RF calculations either, but at a guess, wouldn't the impedance of free space come into it somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

If your "signal" is an EM wave in a vacuum or air and the H field is 1 uA/m then the E field will be that value multiplied by the impedance of free space (377 ohms or \$120\pi\$ ohms to be more precise).

So 1 uA/m maps to 377 uV/m and at those levels there is a power of 377 pW/m\$^2\$.

10 dBuA is 3.162 uA BTW.